# Will there be Volume 2 of Mathematical Statistics by Bickel and Doksum and Robust Asymptotic Statistics by Rieder?

Tags: references

1. It was mentioned that Volume 2 of Mathematical Statistics by Bickel
   and Doksum was scheduled to be published in 2003.  I was wondering
   if I miss something, but why it is not yet available? Is there some
   change of plan?
2. Volume 1 of Robust Asymptotic Statistics by Helmut Rieder was
   published in 90's.  But it seems no volume 2 yet. Am I correct?

Thanks?

Comment: Did you try to email the authors and ask?

Comment: Or the publishers. Or look on Amazon (they sometimes have details of things).  Or ask a librarian (if you are at a university).

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen: not yet. I don't think they will care to reply me.

Comment: @PeterFlom: Amazon doesn't have vol2's.

Comment: Well, the authors re the only one who will know!

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what makes you like Bickel's books?

Answer (score 2):

Volume 2 of Bickel and Doksum has finally been published: [http://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Statistics-Selected-Chapman-Statistical/dp/1498722687/ref=pd_cp_14_1?ie=UTF8&refRID=0BM864NEEG9F092Z2VYT](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1498722687)